# Splitting a string using a vowel or a group of character

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to use regex to split a String using a vowel or a special character.

- Input : `maxtin'asiiro`
- Expected output: `[ ma, xti, n', a, si, i, ro]`

Right now I have managed to split the string using vowels.

```
Arrays.toString(word.split("(?<=[aeiou])")));
```

However, I don't know how I can incorporate the special character `n'` to the regex to get the above output.

Note: `n'` here should be treated as a single special character upon splitting.

I tried the following but it fails with a wrong output.

```
Arrays.toString(word.split("(?<=[aeiou(n')])")));
```

Can someone give me a pointer here?

Comment: Can you show us all "special" characters which might occur here?

Comment: n' is the only special character

Comment: Did you try `(?<=n'|[aeiou])`?

Comment: What is the expected result then?

Comment: @Nikolas I have already shared the expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `n'` is the only special sequence you want to use to split, you may try splitting on an alternation:

```
String word = "maxtin'asiiro";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(word.split("(?<=[aeiou]|n')")));

[ma, xti, n', a, si, i, ro]
```

### Demo

Answer (score 4):

Unlike specifying the `n'` occurrence, I'd go for a more general approach including *any* letter before `'` character.

```
String word = "maxtin'asiiro";
String split[] = word.split("(?<=[aeiou]|[a-zA-Z]')");
```

Results in `[ma, xti, n', a, si, i, ro]`

Nore that:

- `|` works as an *or* operator of tokens between `()` brackets
- `[a-zA-Z]'` stands for `any` letter and `'` character

The demo is ar [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7Qgpjh/1). Note the purple delimiters between characters right after a vowel or a letter followed by `'` character.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nikolas' answer, if you wanted to split after vowels or any character followed by a ', you could also test the following against your input sample:

```
String word = "maxtin'asiiro";
String split[] = word.split("(?<=[aeiou'])");
```

The only difference would be if ' is the first character